# Show options in second menu based on user selection in first menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, multi-select

I'm trying to create an interface that has 2 lists side-by-side. In the beginning the left one will contain different options, and the right one will be blank. The following code creates drop-down boxes but instead I'd like it to be a box with a scroll bar so that **users can select multiple options**.

Once a user selects an option on the left, a list of pre-defined options associated with their selection will appear in the right list.If a user selects more than one option in the left menu, all of the pre-defined options associated with each of their selections will appear in the right-menu.

**Here's the code I have with a fiddle [found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/1669/)**

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="2">Bear</option>
<option value="2">Eagle</option>
<option value="3">BMW<option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
        } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
    });
```

**Instead I'd rather it appear like this:**

[image]

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: What is your specific problem or question?

Comment: How do I create side-by-side lists in which the list on the right will display associated values of the selections a user chooses within the left list. IE: If a user select "Fruit" and "Car" above (via checkbox) , how do I get the associated pre-defined values for these two options to populate the list on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I have updated the snippet to allow removing the related options and to place the lists syde-by-syde.

---

If you don't want a list, you should use a `<ul>` element instead of a drop-down.

```
<ul id="categories"></ul>
<ul id="items"></ul>
```

Store your data in JavaScript, not in the DOM, you will find it more flexible and easier to mantain..

```
var data = [
  [ 'fruit', [ 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange' ] ], 
  [ 'animal', [ 'Wolf', 'Fox', 'Bear', 'Eagle' ] ], 
  [ 'car', [ 'BMW' ] ]
];
```

First, iterate your data appending `<li>` elements to *categories*.
For each one, add an event that will toggle the class *active* and update the related items.

```
for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  $('<li data-category_id="' + i + '" >' + data[i][0] + '</li>'
  ).on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    showItems();
  }).appendTo('#categories');
}
```

To show your items, search into the *data* array for all the items related to `<li>` elements with *active* class.

```
function showItems()
{
  $( '#items' ).html('');
  $('#categories li.active').each( function()
  {
    var categoryId = $(this).data( 'category_id' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < data[categoryId][1].length; i++ )
      $( '#items' ).append( '<li>' + data[categoryId][1][i] + '</li>' );
  });
}
```

As you want to have both lists syde-by-side, add the following CSS:

```
ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

And if you want them to look like boxes where you can scroll:

```
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 125px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here you have the snippet:

```js
var data = [
  [ 'fruit', [ 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange' ] ], 
  [ 'animal', [ 'Wolf', 'Fox', 'Bear', 'Eagle' ] ], 
  [ 'car', [ 'BMW' ] ],
  [ 'other 1', [ 'a', 'b' ] ],
  [ 'other 2', [ '1', '2' ] ]
];

for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  $('<li data-category_id="' + i + '" >' + data[i][0] + '</li>'
  ).on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    showItems();
  }).appendTo('#categories');
} 

function showItems()
{
  $( '#items' ).html('');
  $('#categories li.active').each( function()
  {
    var categoryId = $(this).data( 'category_id' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < data[categoryId][1].length; i++ )
      $( '#items' ).append( '<li>' + data[categoryId][1][i] + '</li>' );
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="categories"></ul>

<ul id="items"></ul>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: David, that looks incredibly promising. It seems to do what I need, so thank you immensely for your time. Will this work across all browsers and versions? What if someone uses IE 8 for instance?

Comment: @Hurmle: As long as I know, everything will work, even under IE8. That is the beautiness of jQuery :)

Comment: Looks like you've earned yourself a checkmark :)  Thank you.

Comment: @Hurmle: Glad it helped :)

Comment: It looks good but how do you pass values when the form is submitted? You will lose widget all functionality like value, events. etc if not used.

Comment: @MaxZoom: as you know, there are several ways to send data to the server, a form is just one of them. Maybe you want to serialize your data `JSON.stringify(obj)` and send it by `$.post()`. Anyway, you can always use a input element, pass it the data and send it the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Make an extra attribute, because you will probably need the value attribute to get the chosen option in the second select.

```
<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1" data-value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="2" data-value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="3" data-value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="4" data-value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="5" data-value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="6" data-value="3">Bear</option>
<option value="7" data-value="3">Eagle</option>
<option value="8" data-value="3">Hawk</option>
<option value="9" data-value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

...then you can filter the second select with your modified code:

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` widget need to has a `multiple` attribute to allow multiple selection. 
**The solution**
We will create a collection of options and store it in variable `entries`.
The second selection options will be initially removed, and populated dynamically once the selection 1 values are set.

Here is code for it:

```js
var entries;
$(document).ready(function() {
  // store options from selection2
  entries = getEntries();

  $("#select1").change(function() {
    var values = $(this).val();
    var $sel2 = $('#select2');

    // Remove all options in selection 2
    $sel2.find('option').each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    // Add only applicable options
    $.each(entries, function(index, entry) {
      if ($.inArray('' + entry.type, values) !== -1) {
        $sel2.append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", entry.value)
          .text(entry.text));
      }
    });

    // select first available option
    $sel2.val($sel2.find('option:first').val());
  });

  $("#select1").trigger('change');

});

function getEntries() {
  var e = [];
  $('#select2').find('option').each(function() {
    e.push(new Entry($(this).data('type'), $(this).val(), $(this).text()));
    $(this).remove();
  });
  return e;
}

// entry structure
function Entry(type, value, text) {
  this.type = type;
  this.value = value;
  this.text = text;
}
```

```css
#select2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 8px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="select1" id="select1" size="3">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option data-type='1' value="1">Banana</option>
  <option data-type='1' value="2">Apple</option>
  <option data-type='1' value="3">Orange</option>
  <option data-type='2' value="4">Wolf</option>
  <option data-type='2' value="5">Fox</option>
  <option data-type='2' value="6">Bear</option>
  <option data-type='2' value="7">Eagle</option>
  <option data-type='3' value="8">BMW</option>
  <option data-type='3' value="9">Lexus</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can't use `hide()` on `<option>` tag....not supported cross browser. Notably it won't work in IE

Comment: also I think Safari doesn't support it.

Comment: To select multiple items in first widget, hold the CTR button when clicking